# Плавная прокрутка страницы с произвольного места до элемента

Tags: javascript, прокрутка

Нужно сделать плавную прокрутку страницы при нажатии на ссылку в меню до определенного элемента. Получилось сделать так, чтобы страница прокручивалась каждый раз с самого верху страницы. Однако, нужно, чтобы можно было прокручивать от текущего видимого места до нужного элемента.
Вот html

```
<ul id='menu'>
    <li><a class='menu-link'>О нас</a></li>
    <li><a class='menu-link'>Фото</a></li>
    <li><a class='menu-link'>Стоимость</a></li>
    <li><a class='menu-link'>Контакты</a></li>
</ul>
```

Те элементы, к которым прокручиваемся, в js заданы просто координатами от начала страницы, поэтому их код сюда не помещаю. Вот js

```
let links = document.getElementsByClassName('menu-link'),
    menu = document.getElementById('menu');

menu.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
    if(event.target && event.target.classList.contains('menu-link')) {
        for(let i = 0; i < links.length; i++) {
            let requestId = setInterval(slowScroll, 1),
                y = 0;

            function slowScroll() {
                if(event.target == links[0]) {
                    if(y == 590) {
                        clearInterval(requestId);
                    } else {
                        y += 10;
                        window.scrollTo(0, y);
                    }
                }
                if(event.target == links[1]) {
                    if(y == 1860) {
                        clearInterval(requestId);
                    } else {
                        y += 20;
                        window.scrollTo(0, y);
                    }
                }
                if(event.target == links[2]) {
                    if(y == 4600) {
                        clearInterval(requestId);
                    } else {
                        y += 50;
                        window.scrollTo(0, y);
                    }
                }
                if(event.target == links[3]) {
                    if(y == 5200) {
                        clearInterval(requestId);
                    } else {
                        y += 100;
                        window.scrollTo(0, y);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

});
```

Хочется решить проблему без прибегания к библиотекам, на простом js.
Заранее спасибо

Answer (score 4, accepted):

А Вам обязательно это делать с помощью javascript? Если нет, вот css код

```
html { scroll-behavior: smooth; }
```

Так же доступен [пример](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/tryit.asp?filename=trycss_scroll_behavior)

[Полное описание свойства scroll-behavior](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_scroll-behavior.asp)